# Can we limit clob datatype column length?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, clob

I am very new to oracle. We got a tablespace issue problem!. We have lot of tables with clob datatype columns. The data in that clob column is not always clob. Sometimes it will be below 4000 and sometimes it is even null. When I searched from user_segments table,it is showing `78.38GB` was taken by `SYS_LOB0345435203$$`.

We have only 96 GB total tablespace. What we are thinkng is whenever we declare some column is clob, irrespective of number of characters it is allotting some predefined space leading us to this problem. Is this correct? If so, how could we solve the issue?

Comment: "*whenever we declare some column is clob .. it is alloting some prdefined space*" - no. That's wrong. The LOB segment will only take as much space as you store in it. You can cross-check the actual size using `select sum(length(your_clob_column)) from your_table`

Comment: Yeah i have checked. So U mean to say we have 78.38GB's of data. All are actual size. Or is there any other possibility for getting this table space issue?

Comment: Show your query how you calculated the size.